# Using jQuery to target an image before page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a website I am working on that has an image gallery, and the user is uploading huge images. The div I have the image gallery containing is set to a certain 400px width to match the layout. The issue I am running into is on page load, for a split second, the first image in the gallery loads on the page at normal size (huge), and then the css kicks in and resizes the image to 400px. I am wondering if there is a way to target and change image size before the site code is rendered. Something like:

```
jQuery( window ).load(function($) {
    //step 1: find the image using the unique css class it is inside
    //step 2: resize image to 400px
    //step 3: let rest of site html/css/jquery load
});
```

I am using `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` in an attempt to target the image before html/css/jquery kicks in. Any insight/help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you put the actual code in? (step 2)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, [verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you've got it the wrong way round: [document.ready happens before document.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: document.ready fires before window.load. window.load fires when all page assets, css, scripts, images are downloaded. Put your css in head section of page.

Comment: I think it's bad idea it will increase the page load time 
When you upload any image at that time make thumbnail image and display that.

Comment: You could use an image resizing software in the backend and serve smaller images to increase page load speed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `width` and `height` attributes to the image element. Your CSS will override these properties when applying styles to a specific class. Furthermore, you don't need to mess with JS.

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="auto">
```

Comment: yes this is an absolute fantastic idea. tested, confirmed; moving to production now!